# Regexp skip pattern

Tags: c#, regex

**Problem**

I need to replace all asterisk symbols('*') with percent symbol('%'). The asterisk symbols in square brackets should be ignored.

**Example**

```
    [Test]
    public void Replace_all_asterisks_outside_the_square_brackets()
    {
        var input = "Hel[*o], w*rld!";
        var output = Regex.Replace(input, "What_pattern_should_be_there?", "%")

        Assert.AreEqual("Hel[*o], w%rld!", output));
    }
```

Comment: +1 for writing a unit test in your question.

Comment: Depending on the exact rules of your string you probably can find a pattern to replace the asterisks without a callback (as you've asked), be it'd be much easier if you define clear rules: do you have escaped characters? Do you have unmatched brackets? If you do, how would you handle different edge cases? Can bracket blocks be nested?

Comment: @Koby - Your pattern `@"\[[^\]]*\]|(?<Asterisk>\*)` and callback function was enough to solve my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a look ahead:

```
\*(?![^\[\]]*\])
```

Here's a bit stronger solution, which takes care of `[]` blocks better, and even escaped `\[` characters:

```
string text = @"h*H\[el[*o], w*rl\]d!";
string pattern = @"
\\.                 # Match an escaped character. (to skip over it)
|
\[                  # Match a character class 
    (?:\\.|[^\]])*  # which may also contain escaped characters (to skip over it)
\]
|
(?<Asterisk>\*)     # Match `*` and add it to a group.
";

text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern,
    match => match.Groups["Asterisk"].Success ? "%" : match.Value,
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

If you don't care about escaped characters you can simplify it to:

```
\[          # Skip a character class
    [^\]]*  # until the first ']'
\]
|
(?<Asterisk>\*)
```

Which can be written without comments as: `@"\[[^\]]*\]|(?<Asterisk>\*)"`.

To understand why it works we need to understand how Regex.Replace works: for every position in the string it tries to match the regex. If it fails, it moves one *character*. If it succeeds, it moves over the whole match.
Here, we have dummy matches for the `[...]` blocks so we may skip over the asterisks we don't want to replace, and match only the lonely ones. That decision is made in a callback function that checks if `Asterisk` was matched or not.

Comment: Best answer so far, but the following case is not working: `Hel*o], w*rld!` In this example, the first asterisk is not in square brackets and therefore should be replaced. Your regex however skips it.

Comment: @Daniel - try the next one. I'll explain it better later, I don't have the time at the moment.

Comment: It passes my test as described below. Nice one! I am not even going to try to understand it. ;-) In my opinion, that's also a big problem with solving this task with pure RegEx: It is hard to maintain. I admit, my solution isn't much clearer ;-)

Comment: @Daniel - I've simplified it a little and added some explanation, I hope you'll a least *try* to understand it this time `:)`

Comment: Contrary to my comment, I tried to understand the complex version anyway and it was clear :-)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't come up with a pure RegEx solution. Therefore I am providing you with a pragmatic solution. I tested it and it works:

```
[Test]
public void Replace_all_asterisks_outside_the_square_brackets()
{
    var input = "H*]e*l[*o], w*rl[*d*o] [o*] [o*o].";
    var actual = ReplaceAsterisksNotInSquareBrackets(input);
    var expected = "H%]e%l[*o], w%rl[*d*o] [o*] [o*o].";

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

private static string ReplaceAsterisksNotInSquareBrackets(string s)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<=\[[^\[\]]*)(?<asterisk>\*)(?=[^\[\]]*\])");

    var matches = rx.Matches(s);
    s = s.Replace('*', '%');

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        s = s.Remove(match.Groups["asterisk"].Index, 1);
        s = s.Insert(match.Groups["asterisk"].Index, "*");
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

***EDITED***

Okay here is my final attempt ;)

Using negative lookbehind `(?<!)` and negative lookahead `(?!)`.

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\[)\*(?!\])", "%");
```

This also passes the test in the comment to another answer `"Hel*o], w*rld!"`

Comment: -1: Please read his question! You are missing the real problem: Skipping the asterisks in square brackets

Comment: Ah - the asterix in square brackets need to be ignored. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Check with this string: `H*]e*l[*o], w*rl[*d*o] [o*] [o*o].` Quite a tricky problem...