# RegEx match strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a question related to regular expressions in c#.

I want to find text between " characters.
Example:

```
 Enum resultado = SPDialogBox.Instance.show<ACTION_ENUMs.TORNEO_SORTEAR>("Esto es una prueba");
```

Matches: `Esto es una prueba`

But, in this example

```
Enum resultado = SPDialogBox.Instance.show<ACTION_ENUMs.TORNEO_SORTEAR>("Esto es una prueba");
pKR_MESAPUESTOASIGNACION.CONFIGTORNEO_ID = Valid.GetInt(dr.Cells["CONFIGTORNEO_ID"].Value);
```

Matches: `Esto es una prueba` but must not match `CONFIGTORNEO_ID`, because it is written between square brackets (`[]`)

In brief, I want to match string between double quote (`"`) characters, but that string must not be written between square brackets (`[]`).

Here is my code:

```
var pattern = "\"(.*?)\"";
var matches = Regex.Matches(fullCode, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

That pattern matches all string between `"` characters, but how can I modify the pattern to exclude those string that are written between square brackets?

-- edit ---

here is another example:

```
List<String> IdSorteados = new List<String>();
int TablesToSort = 0;
foreach (UltraGridRow dr in fg.hfg_Rows)
{
    if (dr.Cells["MESA_ID"].Value == DBNull.Value && dr.Cells["Puesto"].Value == DBNull.Value && !Valid.GetBoolean(dr.Cells["BELIMINADO"].Value) && (Valid.GetBoolean(dr.Cells["Seleccionado"].Value) || SortearTodo))
        TablesToSort++;
    }
```

The expression must not match `MESA_ID` ( found within `Cells["MESA_ID"].Value` ) nor `Puesto` (found within `Cells["Puesto"].Value` ). It also must not match `].Value == DBNull.Value && dr.Cells[` (found within `["MESA_ID"].Value == DBNull.Value && dr.Cells["Puesto"]` )

I hope I have made my intent clear.

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153980/regexp-skip-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple use a negative look-behind:

```
(?<!\[)
```

Basically, only match a string when not preceded by a `[`. [Example here](http://ideone.com/IYBjL), and code as follows:

```
String fullCode = "Enum resultado = SPDialogBox.Instance.show<ACTION_ENUMs.TORNEO_SORTEAR>(\"Esto es una prueba\");\r\n"
                + "pKR_MESAPUESTOASIGNACION.CONFIGTORNEO_ID = Valid.GetInt(dr.Cells[\"CONFIGTORNEO_ID\"].Value);";
String pattern = @"(?<!\[)\x22(.*?)\x22";
var matches = Regex.Matches(fullCode, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works great. It matches: if (dr.Cells["MESA_ID"].Value == DBNull.Value && dr.Cells["Puesto"].Value == DBNull  =>>> ].Value == DBNull.Value && dr.Cells[. How can i indicate that i don`t want the string to starts with ] and ends with [??

Comment: @Müsli: Update your question with a couple more versions of example content you're filtering and I'll work out a solution that works for most cases. Also be sure to outline what you'd like found/returned.

Comment: @Müsli: off-hand, try `@"(?<!\[)\x22(?!\])(.*?)\x22"`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid matching quoted nested inside square brackets, you need to check that one of the following is true:

- The last non-whitespace character preceding the opening double quote is *not* a `[`, or
- The first non-whitespace character following the closing double-quote is *not* a `]`

This can be done using this regexp:

```
(?<!\[\s*)\"[^"]*\"(?!\s*\])
```

It uses the [*lookaround*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) feature of .NET regexp engine.

Note how this expression avoids the reluctant qualifier `?` inside the quoted string by using `[^"]*` instead of `.*?`.

Comment: That catches the content _inside_ the square brackets [flawlessly](http://regexr.com?30m05).

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks, I forgot asterisks after my `\s`. It's now fixed.

Comment: Indeed. I figured as much, but wanted to give you the opportunity to fix. And how's that old saying go? Quantifiers over qualifiers? ;p

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
^[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\".*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Many times I have to parse source code files (php|cpp|java|js|css|etc) and do some regexp replacements. To avoid replacing some strings/messages I mask all strings before doing my replacements, so I have to capture all possible strings and mask them.

This is how I capture all strings: `/(['"])(\\\1|.)*?\1/gm`
which means:

- capture everything that starts with single|double quote: `['"]`
- it may be followed by zero or more characters, even by the same quote symbol (which is not considered the end of the string) if it's preceded by forward-slash (the escape `\` operator): `(\\\1|.)*`
- make sure that the above pattern stops at the first occurrence and not at its last match (ie. don't be greedy): `?`
- finally our string ends when it's followed by the same starting single|double quote: `\1`

I want this search to be made both globally (to capture all possible matches) and also multi-line (a string may not continue on a new line delimited by CRLF, right?)

Perhaps you are interested not only to find but also to capture these strings groups so make sure you put within group delimiter the `(\\\1|.)*?` which gives the final pattern:

> `([\'"])((\\\1|.)*?)\1`

Examples of strings captured:

```
defined ( 'WP_DEBUG' ) || define( '\WP_DEBUG', true );
echo 'class="input-text card-number" type="text" maxlength="20"';
echo 'How are you? I\'m fine, thank you';
```

[Check my pattern in an online regex tester](https://regex101.com/?regex=%28%5B%5C%27%22%5D%29%28%28%5C%5C%5C1%7C.%29%2A%3F%29%5C1&options=gm&text=defined+%28+%27WP_DEBUG%27+%29+||+define%28+%27%5CWP_DEBUG%27%2C+true+%29%3B%0Aecho+%27class%3D%22input-text+card-number%22+type%3D%22text%22+maxlength%3D%2220%22%27%3B%0Aecho+%27How+are+you%3F+I%5C%27m+fine%2C+thank+you%27%3B).